# Rewriting a 4th order linear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the following 4th order linear pde:
$$
u_{xxyy}+a u_{xxy}+bu_{yy}+cu_y+du_x=0
$$
for $u(x,y)\in C^2\left([0,1]\times \mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right) $.

Is it possible to rewrite this equation in the form:
$$
U_y(y)= \mathcal{L} U(y)
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the infinitesimal generator of a strongly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators on $C^2\left([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n\right) $?

Comment: The final subscript $s$?

Comment: @user10354138 it was a typo, sorry...